# MATLAB - write cell array to csv file

Tags: matlab, file-io, csv

I have a cell array that has both characters and numbers as values. What is the simplest way to output it in a csv file, row by row, maintaining the structure of the cell array?
For example, if the cell array is

```
[abc] [1] [131]
[def] [] []
[gh] [13] [999]
```

I want the file to look like

```
abc,1,131
def,,
gh,13,999
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752102/outputing-cell-array-to-csv-file-matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
%# cellarray
C = {
    'abc' [1]  [131]
    'def' []   []
    'gh'  [13] [999]
};

%# write line-by-line
fid = fopen('file.csv','wt');
for i=1:size(C,1)
    fprintf(fid, '%s,%d,%d\n', C{i,:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Should this file already exist or I create it this way? I am getting   ??? Error using ==> fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> parseTickData at 134
    fprintf(fd, '%s,%f,%d%f%d%f%d\n', C{i,:});

Comment: @Trup: it should create a new file if it didn't already exist, and overwrite it if it did.. Also can you show us what a row in your actual cellarray looks like?