# Writing a matlab cell to a csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, cell

So I have a cell that has the following structure:

```
result{index} = {name, mean(winternights), max(winternights), var(winternights), sum(winternights)};
```

The **name** variable is a string but the rest are numbers. The only way I've found to write a cell to a csv file is the following:

```
fid = fopen('Measurements.csv','wt');
for i=1:size(result,1)
    fprintf(fid, '%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n', result{i,:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

But this throws an error: **??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `result`, the call `result{i} = {...}` places a cell array inside the ith element of the cell array `result`. Thus, you need to change your file-writing code to the following

```
fid = fopen('Measurements.csv','wt');
for i=1:size(result,1)
    fprintf(fid, '%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n', result{i}{:});
end
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Similar issue** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004146/matlab-write-cell-array-to-csv-file).

You can do either this:

```
[nrows,ncols]= size(mycell);

filename = 'celldata.dat';
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');

for row=1:nrows
    fprintf(fid, '%s %d %d %d\n', mycell{row,:});
end

fclose(fid);
```

Or you can use [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4400-cell-array-to-csv-file-cell2csv-m) **cell2csv** from Matlab central.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. **celldisp** is for displaying the cell, I don't think I can use it to write the cell to a csv file.