# Problems using matlab to print a histogram to a file

Tags: linux, matlab

I am trying to create a histogram of numbers in an array. I am using Matlab to do this. I am connecting via ssh so I can only use Matlab in the terminal on my Linux computer. I am trying to create a histogram of the data in the array and save it as a .png. I know that in order for me to save this I need to use the `print` function. So far my attempt has been the following:

```
h=hist(array) 
print(h,'-dpng','hist1.png')
```

which told me that there is no variable defined as `-dpng` but I thought that the point of that was to specify the file type.

Then I just deleted the `-dpng` and ran it as

```
print(h,'hist1.png')
```

to which it told me *"Handle must be scalar, vector, or cell-array of vectors"*

At this point I don't quite know what to do next. I would like for someone to help me figure out how to print this histogram to a .png file. Thank you.

Comment: Install octave: it is an open-source variant of matlab.

Comment: @Eddy_Em I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 6):

`hist` does not return a figure handle, you could to do something similar to:

```
h = figure;
hist(array);
print(h, '-dpng', 'hist1.png');
```

to save the histogram.

Answer (score 2):

By itself, the function hist(array) plots a histogram.  If you assign the output to a variable, it returns the binned values of array, not the handle to your plot.

```
f = figure;
hist(array)
saveas(f,'hist.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

you may would like to output the array to a csv file.

```
fid = fopen('file.csv','wt');
for i=1:size(arr)
    fprintf(fid, '%s,%d,%d\n','element number' ,i ,arr(i));
end
fclose(fid);
```

See this link, you should be able to change the answers there to your needs: [Outputing cell array to CSV file ( MATLAB )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752102/outputing-cell-array-to-csv-file-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use figure handle unless you want to print not current figure. By default `print` uses `gcf` that returns handle for current figure.

So you just can do:

```
hist(array) 
print('-dpng','hist1.png')
```

---

You got an error that there is no variable defined as `-dpng` probably because you forgot one quote symbol and used `-dpng'`.